# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating my google play services to rev 28 i'm getting this error. Im not sure why this is happening as it was working fine before.

here is my **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.matsoltech.pakistancurrentaffairs"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 11
    versionName "2.1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     compile files('src/main/libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
     compile files('src/main/libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
     compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
     compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
}
```

and

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

So, can anyone please tell me where is the problem? as the code was working fine before the update of GooglePlayServices.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

change your google-services in Project dependencies to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

This will fix it.

Comment: That fixed it, huge thanks!. Google forgot to update their official doc. It's still mentioning classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'

Comment: where does google tell to developers to put this classpath ?? I don't see com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3  classpath or 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

Comment: Primitive solution to a complex problem.

Answer (score 7):

Use these dependencies for the project build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

and put this at the end of the app-level build.gradle file (after the dependencies). For some reason I don't understand if you put it at the beginning it will cause problems, make sure you place it at the end.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: From where did you get this information to use 2.0.0-aplpha3?
Also is is stable to use alpha3 dependency?

Comment: Thanks!  I'd have spent all day fixing this if I didn't know to move the plugin to the bottom of the list!!!!

Answer (score 4):

you need to add this

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

and remove this

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using play-services-analytics: 
delete this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

The entire library is heavy. And now you can take the part that you need.
Analitycs, gcm etc.
So you're actually taking twice Analytics

Comment: I tried this one before but didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Current version is 2.0.0-beta6...move

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

from the top to the bottom after dependencies as suggested though, I added it to the bottom not realizing it was already at the top. Having it twice by accident annoyed me.

Comment: I noticed that you're supposed to put the `apply plugin` to the *bottom* of the gradle file from your comment, and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me is to get latest version of google services from below link. Just needed to use latest version for `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta4'`

https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/

Comment: The latest is actually `2.0.0-beta4`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky at the time I posted the answer, it was latest.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

Comment: While this code block might answer the question, Please provide relevant info so that other can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Import the google-services.json physically where your project resides
eg:C:\Users\User\Desktop\yourproject\

put your google-services.json here in app folder of yourprojects
C:\Users\User\Desktop\yourproject\app <----------in this

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem when i was a newbie to Android Development.
Though you had everything in place like below

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

and you might be placed even the below line in your **build.gradle(app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

placing the above piece of code at the bottom of your **build.gradle** file fix your error

More important thing check your **build.gradle(project level)** file

```
apply plugin:  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }'
```

com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0 is placed or not .it won't support old verisons

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the play services version is latest that you used

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, go to the Project-->platform..>android-->.gradlefile and modify the line

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem, too. What you say is not the key.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' must at dependencies!

Answer (score 0):

- I copied the `google-services.json` file i downloaded and pasted it in `app root` folder i.e  in your android studio,
- Please also make sure the 'google-services.json' file you downloaded has the same name with the one you pasted in the root directory.

**This worked for me. thanks**