# Android Google Services Plugin Issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

While running GCM Sender Application I am Getting this type of Exception

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources] :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. Information:BUILD
> >     FAILED Information:Total time: 2.942 secs Information:1 error
> >     Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console

Can any One Please Clarify

Comment: I am download the code from git hub and Same code try to run in Android studio I am Getting above exception. I have searched all the possible solutions from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342306/file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google-service and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556780/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices-please-fix/33558478#33558478 but same exception will come can any one resolve my issue..

Answer (score 0):

The way how to integrate Google Play Services has recently changed. You have to add a google-services.json.

Here you will find information how to get this config file and how to integrate GCM:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: I will try along with video demonstration after completion I will run app. Then it shows Build fail with the above Exception can you send any any working Example Please

Comment: You should show some of your code. Copy and Paste an exception is not quite helpful. How does your build.gradle files look like? Where is your google-services.json placed. How is your general app setup.

Comment: build.gradle(Module app) : dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
}

Comment: build.gradle(Project: gcm) buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

Comment: I didn't Understand can you Please explain I am new to this Stackoverflow

Comment: In the question sections, there is a edit-button. Afterwards you can edit your question and add the necessary information there (well-formatted). For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This sample uses the Google Services Plugin, which requires that you have the google-services.json file in the app directory of your project.

[See this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start), being sure to get the configuration file and add it to the app directory of your Android project.

Also be sure to update the API key value in GcmSender.java.

Answer (score 0):

You need To:

1-Go to https://console.firebase.google.com
2-Create a project.
3-Then go and click on Add Firebase to your Android app
4- Add (Package name, Debug signing certificate SHA-1)
5- Then Firebase will generate google-services.json
6- Copy this file and add it to your project root
7- Then follow every steps